# How can I rename a file in a different path without changing the current directory or writing the path twice?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

For example, I want to rename `tif/fat/tul/codes/MyCode.pl` to `TheCode.pl` in the same directory. Currently I know I can use this:

```
mv tif/fat/tul/codes/MyCode.pl tif/fat/tul/codes/TheCode.pl
```

but that requires me to repeat typing the full path (can be annoying if the path is quite long)

or I can use

```
cd mv tif/fat/tul/codes/
mv MyCode.pl TheCode.pl
```

The drawback being I have to type 2 commands, and have to change the current directory is undesirable in many cases.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://superuser.com/questions/298081/in-bash-how-can-i-rename-a-file-without-repeating-the-path

Comment: Based on the duplicate, the command you should use is `mv tif/fat/tul/codes/{My,The}Code.pl`

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is open another shell (like bash) in your current one, `cd` to the directory of the file, and then `mv`.
Then you just close the shell with Ctrl+D (which moves back to your previous directory).

Answer (score -1):

```
find /path/to/dir/ -iname MyCode.pl -execdir mv MyCode.pl TheCode.pl
```

`/path/to/dir` is path of directory in which you want to rename files.

Note: This will rename all files in directory `/path/to/dir/` and its subdirectory.

Comment: That's both cumbersome and incorrect. -1